# How to extract part of a JSON as another JSON and separate them several JSON files on Python

Tags: python, json, string, pandas, list

I started learning data analysis using Python. And I have been trying to use [Adzuna dataset](https://developer.adzuna.com/docs/search) for my course project. The response from my API call looks like this:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "salary_min": 50000,
      "longitude": -0.776902,
      "location": {
        "__CLASS__": "Adzuna::API::Response::Location",
        "area": [
          "UK",
          "South East England",
          "Marlow"
        ],
        "display_name": "Marlow, Buckinghamshire"
      },
      "salary_is_predicted": 0,
      "description": "JavaScript Developer Corporate ...",
      "__CLASS__": "Adzuna::API::Response::Job",
      "created": "2013-11-08T18:07:39Z",
      "latitude": 51.571999,
      "redirect_url": "http://adzuna.co.uk/jobs/land/ad/129698749...",
      "title": "Javascript Developer",
      "category": {
        "__CLASS__": "Adzuna::API::Response::Category",
        "label": "IT Jobs",
        "tag": "it-jobs"
      },
      "id": "129698749",
      "salary_max": 55000,
      "company": {
        "__CLASS__": "Adzuna::API::Response::Company",
        "display_name": "Corporate Project Solutions"
      },
      "contract_type": "permanent"
    },
    ... another 19 samples here ...
  ],
  "mean": 43900.46, 
  "__CLASS__": "Adzuna::API::Response::JobSearchResults",
  "count": 74433
}
```

My goal is to extract 20 samples under "results" individually so that I can create a numpy dataset later for data analysis. So, I wrote Python like this:

```
item_dict = json.loads(response.text)
# Since "results" start/end with [ and ], Python treats it as a list. So, I need to remove them.
string_data = str(item_dict['results']).lstrip("[")
string_data = string_data.rstrip("]")

# Convert "results" string back to JSON, then extract each sample from 20 samples
json_results_data = json.loads(string_data)
for sample in json_results_data:
  print(sample)
```

However, `json_results_data = json.loads(string_data)` doesn't convert the "results" string to JSON well. I am new to Python, so I may be asking a stupid question, but please let me know if you can figure out an easy way to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: if you're using `requests` just do `response.json()`. the data should be one dictionary so not sure why you are doing string manipulation

Comment: @gold_cy  Yes, ```response.json()``` is a dictionary, but if I write ```(responce.json())['results']```, this is treated as a list, because it start/end with "[]", so I decided to remove [] as a string thentried to convert it back to JSON or a dictionary. (Am I making sense?)

Comment: @gold_cy But you are right, ```json.loads(response.text)``` should be just ```response.json``` instead. I will revise it now on the question.

Comment: if `results` is a list just iterate over it to manipulate the objects within it, don't try to do some string manipulation

Comment: It is a list, but each sample is separated by ```,``` (comma), which is not how I want to separate...

Comment: if not by a comma what do you want to seperate by and why?

Comment: show the desired input. also yes, commas are how lists separate items. it's up to you to iterate over that list and manipulate it

Comment: @gold_cy Yes, I now understand the structure. You guys are right. It should be separated by a comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

What you are trying to achieve is organize your data from a json object. The first line in your code `item_dict = json.loads(response.text)` returns you a `dict` object and hence you could simply use that.

I would show two methods:

1. Using a `pandas.DataFrame` to organize your data.
2. Using a for loop to just print your data.

But note that, the `pandas.DataFrame` allows you to quickly convert your data into a numpy array as well (use: `df.to_numpy()`)

```py
import pandas as pd

results = response.json['results'] # item_dict['results']
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(df)
# df.to_numpy()
```

**output**:

```sh
      a    b     c     d      e
0   1.0  2.0   NaN   dog   True
1  20.0  2.0   0.0   cat   True
2   1.0  NaN   NaN  bird   True
3   NaN  2.0  88.0   pig  False
```

Instead, if you just want to print out each dictionary inside `results`, you could just do this:

```py
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

### Dummy Data

```py
item_dict = {
    'results': [
                {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': None, 'd': 'dog', 'e': True}, 
                {'a': 20, 'b': 2, 'c': 0, 'd': 'cat', 'e': True}, 
                {'a': 1, 'b': None, 'c': None, 'd': 'bird', 'e': True},
                {'a': None, 'b': 2, 'c': 88, 'd': 'pig', 'e': False}
    ],
    "mean": 43900.46, 
    "__CLASS__": "Adzuna::API::Response::JobSearchResults",
    "count": 74433
}
```

Comment: nothing here specifies `pandas` so suggesting an answer with a large overhead for a 3rd party library like `pandas`, makes no sense

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am not using Panda this time, but this helped me deepen my understanding

Comment: @Tak Please give this a shot and let me know if you have any questions. Pandas is very powerful in data-analysis, and you may consider using it.

Comment: @Tak, how are you consolidating your individual dicts: I mean how do you plan to look at all the 19 dicts? You would need to either use a list (with in this case is `results`), or an array (`df.to_numpy()`) or the dataframe (`df`). Do you have anything else in mind?

Comment: @gold_cy The question focuses on organization of data. Even if the individual dicts are printed, it does not help in consolidating the data for further analysis. Which is why I suggested use of `pandas` and if necessary `numpy` array as you already have a list (`results`). I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I tried your solution by myself, and it now totally makes sense why I should use ```pandas``` to prepare for the data analysis (I plan to use sklearn). Let me see which one works better for the sklearn analysis and I may change the acceptance tick... (Not sure if it's ethical to change the acceptance tick on StackOverflow though...)

Comment: @gold_cy Fair enough. **BUT** it's _your_ opinion. See the last comment by the OP. He clearly says that it makes sense to him/her.

Comment: you're right it is my opinion, and in my opinion this deserves a downvote for suggesting to use `pandas` when it was not required. does that make sense? also don't ask for upvotes....

Comment: @Tak Could you please consider **`voting up`** if you think my solution helped?

Comment: Yes I actually decided to go with your solution! Thank you so much for your help. I think I've already voted up?

Comment: @Tak Great! if you think my solution is best suited, please consider **`accepting`** it as well. Have fun with `pandas`!

Answer (score 1):

Stop stipping the square brackets... its meant to be a list.

Try this

```py
item_dict = json.loads(response.text)

for sample in item_dict["results"]:
  print(sample)
```

Your issue was you thought you had a dict (json) but you have a list of dicts.

Comment: Thank you. I think I interpreted it in a too complicated way... Your solution seems to work well. Please let me double-check!

Comment: @Tak No problem. Don't forget to tick my answer if it helped you.